# VBA: Auto-adjusting all y-axes range based on series collection

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to update the y-axis of all charts based on the max and min of all series (more than 1) in EACH of the particular charts. (Therefore all the charts will be updated differently depending on the series in them). How can I do this? As far as I know, there is no simple SeriesCollection(all) option so I'm trying to use a loop. Any better suggestions are welcome.

```
Public Sub UpdateChartAxes()

Dim objChart As ChartObject
For Each objChart In Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects
    UpdateChartAxis objChart
Next objChart

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateChartAxis(ByVal objChart As ChartObject)
On Error GoTo CleanFail

Dim lower As Double
Dim upper As Double
Dim srs As Series

lower = 100
upper = 0

With objChart.Chart
For Each srs In .SeriesCollection
If Application.RoundDown(Application.Aggregate(15, 6, srs, 1), 0) < lower _
    Then lower = Application.RoundDown(Application.Aggregate(15, 6, srs, 1), 0)

If Application.RoundUp(Application.Aggregate(14, 6, srs, 1), 0) > upper _
    Then upper = Application.RoundUp(Application.Aggregate(14, 6, srs, 1), 0)
Next srs

.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = lower
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = upper
End With

CleanExit:
Exit Sub

CleanFail:
Debug.Print lower
Debug.Print "Failed updating axes for chart '" & objChart.Name & "'.Message: " & Err.Description
Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: are you getting an error ? at which line does your code jumps to `CleanFail` ?

Comment: you are missing the comma, change your `For Each srs In SeriesCollection` to `For Each srs In .SeriesCollection` (it's related to your `With objChart.Chart`)

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. In any case, I'm getting the error "Application-defined or object-defined error" for all the charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is "srs" within the for-loop (Aggregate doesn't take series objects). Use "srs.Values" instead.